# What do these lein folders do?

Tags: clojure, clojurescript, leiningen

In my project directory, there are two folders named as follows:

```
./.repl-1.7.170
./.cljs_node_repl
```

I believe these folders are automatically generated. What are they for? Is it OK to delete them periodically when cleaning up?

Comment: They are generated, but there is usually no need to clean them up. `lein clean` should clean them.

Answer (score 1):

I think these are both working directories used by the REPL when compiling REPL-related code.

In either case, why do you need to delete them?

The only consideration around this I can think of is wanting to make sure they don't somehow get committed to source code control. For that you can just use ignores or excludes if for example, you are using `git`.